# How can I unify my stereo audio output to make it mono?

Tags: audio, cinnamon, devuan, accessibility

I use stereo speakers or headphones, and for "accessibility-related" reasons, I need to have the same audio play from both sides. Now, I don't need this for some specific audio file - which I could edit to downmix to mono; I need this for the audio output of my Linux system.

How can I make this happen?

System info:

- Devuan GNU/Linux Daedalus
- Cinnamon desktop environment 5.6.7
- Linux kernel 6.1.0.
- Using USB headphones at times, on-board audio analog output at other times.

Additional complication which you can tackle if you'd like, or just ignore: I would like to have this happen only for the USB headphones.

Comment: Don't know from the top of my head, but it will be relevant for other answerers as well: does cinnamon on devuan use pipewire, pulseaudio or some other audio system?

Comment: There is an example for pulseaudio on [archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Remap_stereo_to_mono).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Well, `pavucontrol` works, and `/usr/bin/pulseaudio` is working in the background, so probably that.